# Reading text file with multiple space as delimiter and containing empty fields in R

Tags: r, read.table

I have a large text file using single and multiple spaces as the delimiter but also contains some blank fields. 
I read this in as such:

```
df = read.table(text = 
"E C  588784   228    0.346  48.606  -0.870   0.005   0.045   0.951
E P  588784   229    0.407  57.753  -1.975   0.005   0.045   0.951
E A  5784   230    0.554  61.073  -2.308   0.005   0.045   0.951
  X  5784   231    0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
E E  5784   232    0.541  94.495  -1.847   0.005   0.015   0.979
E L  5784   233    0.310  56.724  -2.325   0.018   0.047   0.935", fill = T)

print(df)

  V1   V2   V3  V4    V5     V6     V7    V8    V9   V10
1  E    C 588784 228 0.346 48.606 -0.870 0.005 0.045 0.951
2  E    P 588784 229 0.407 57.753 -1.975 0.005 0.045 0.951
3  E    A 5784 230 0.554 61.073 -2.308 0.005 0.045 0.951
4  X 5784  231   0 0.000  0.000  0.000 0.000 0.000    NA
5  E    E 5784 232 0.541 94.495 -1.847 0.005 0.015 0.979
6  E    L 5784 233 0.310 56.724 -2.325 0.018 0.047 0.935
```

Now the question is how to deal with this. Given that there is some consistency in which fields are sometimes blank it's manageable to find those cases and outline them correctly but I was wondering if there is a more straightforward approach.

EDITED

Comment: This looks more like a fixed width data format than a delimited format. You should probably try `read_fwf` from `readr` or the base `read.fwf()` function.

Comment: The values in V3 do differ somewhat in width at times, it seems that the spaces between fields do stay the same at all times.

Comment: As MrFlick mentions, use: `require(readr); read_fwf(my_text, fwf_empty(my_text))`

Comment: Read it in with `readLines()` not worrying about separators, then use regex to replace any amount of white space with a single tab, then use `read.table`.

Comment: @Floo0 I think this would work but I need to read in my data using readLines first. It seems read_fwf is having problems with using the character vector created by readLines as input. I'm getting a non-descriptive error which just returns the first few lines of the character vector.

Comment: @Gregor Your approach worked, thanks!